# how create a new div parent for some divs via jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a html code like this:

```
<div class="tiltleclass"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="tiltleclass"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="tiltleclass"></div>
```

What can I do when I click on a div with "tiltleclass" class the divs between this div till next div with "tiltleclass" class toggle?
In my program this structure is in many pages so I can't get new classes to them.
Is there a way in jquery to do this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/suzq4o7r/1/

Comment: Not sure why the title says "how create a new div parent for some divs via jquery" and description asks for something else..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works, using jQuery's [`nextUntil()` method](http://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/):

```
$(".tiltleclass").on('click', function() {
     $(this).nextUntil(".tiltleclass").toggle();
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2ss4L1wh/).

Comment: @user3104188 You can use `.toggle(500);` in this method to add a smooth effect

Answer (score 0):

You can use [nextUntil](http://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/) as follows:

```
$(".tiltleclass").click(function(){
  $(this).nextUntil(".tiltleclass").toggle();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/xbt6jvp2/)

Comment: That should be `toggle`

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen  typo... thnx. BTW, you can just edit the answer to fix the typo instead of adding the same answer once again. That's why you're given that privilege… ;)

Comment: @user3104188 glad it helped. Still wondering why you accepted the late answer.. ah, nvm.